# md-tab hide title if only one tab

Tags: angular, user-interface, tabs, angular-ui

I am new to Angular, I am using md-tab-group and md-tab to show information, it basicly likes:

```
    <md-tab-group *ngIf="obj">
       <md-tab *ngIf="obj.info1">
           .....
       </md-tab>
      <md-tab *ngIf="obj.info2">
           .....
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab *ngIf="obj.info3">
           .....
      </md-tab>
    </md-tab-group>
```

now I was asked to hide the tab label if only one tab, but Im not sure how to do that. 
Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "the selector it's self"? Whole `md-tab-group` ?

Comment: sorry for the misleading information. I mean if there is only one tab, it is unnecessary to select that tab. I tried to empty the label, but there is still a blank tab selector there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple a `*ngIf` statement to check the length of your array. If it's greater than 1, use `md-tab`, if it's `== 1`, then use any normal content area tag like `<p></p>`. I don't think it's possible to hide `md-tab-label` selector and only show the `md-tab-content` for an `md-tab`.

Here' the solution that I could think of:

```
<h1>Array Length > 1</h1>

<md-tab-group *ngIf="obj.length > 1">
  <md-tab *ngFor="let item of obj" [label]="item.title">{{ item.content }}</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>

<h1>Array Length 1</h1>

<p *ngIf="obj.length == 1">
 {{ obj[0].content }}
</p>
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mBNtjokqAfw2tHzUtRb3?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank u! I will have a try then give a feedback later